# Decoding Base64 string from URL c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to decode the following  Base64 string that i'm getting from a url like so:

```
string msgFromUrl = "j3oaCbiwIfZF1QFa%2FHkMaW5lVpnOMBsA5wYI"; 
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(msgFromUrl);
string decoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
Console.WriteLine(decoded);
```

I am getting an error on the string that i need to decode. The error i'm getting is:

```
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
```

I have realised that there is a percentage symbol in the string and when i try remove it i come short of the valid length of Base64 char. Since i'm retrieving  this from a url, could there be anything hidden or do i have to do more than i have done in order to decode the encoded string?

Thank you .

Comment: Is the `%2F` supposed to be a `/`?  Maybe URL-decode the value before Base64-decoding it.

Comment: Most likely the URL contains a URL encoded form of the actual Base64 string. `%2FH` is the URL encoding for `/`

Comment: This works: `Convert.FromBase64String(Uri.UnescapeDataString("j3oaCbiwIfZF1QFa%2FHkMaW5lVpnOMBsA5wYI"))`. Although it would be better if only Url encoding was used.

Comment: It was probably double encoded at source  to prevent /+ breaking a query string

Comment: Usually issue like this are due to not receiving all the data before using the data.  First check that length of string match the length that was sent.

Comment: PS, the double decoding works but the result is NOT a valid UTF8 string. You'll get a lot of �, the Unicode replacement character when there are conversion errors. Unicode returns Chinese characters but ends with ۧ�. What is this string supposed to contain?

Comment: Yeah that is rc4 string that needs to be decoded

Answer (score -1):

In fact, there is a way to do this, but to do that you have to understand the url encoding, for example, when data is sent in Arabic via the url address, you will notice that the data is something like this:

> %D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%A2%20%D8%A7%D8%B5%D8%AF%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%89

But it depends on the browser in general. There are browsers such as the Opera browser for the phone that does not work with the url encoding system. Instead, all values ​​are sent as they are and without change, unlike other browsers such as Google Chrome, so you will have to first decode the value first, so we can come up with this example :-

```
<script> function fromURL(){ var url = "https://www.code-editor.com?Code=PGh0bWw+CjxoZWFkPg=="; var Base64_text = url.searchParams.get("Code"); console.log(atob(Base64_text. replaceAll(" ","+"))); } </script>
```

As you can see in some browsers, the + sign is replaced with a space, so all we will do is before taking the data. We first replace all spaces with a + sign, and thus the problem is solved as shown in the previous example, and you can send Base64 via the url without any restrictions